# Play async WS API explained

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework

I just started learning about Play framework lately and really like it so far.
There is just one thing that isn't clear to me. I'm a Java developer, with an blocking
and multi-threaded way of thinking so async programming is a little new to me.

So, Play framework uses an asynchronous WS API which doesn't block thread that calls it, nor
it **blocks or spawns any other thread**. When doing some async programming usually you have
to spawn a new thread and then make a WS call so you don't block your main thread. So my question here is how does Play's WS API manages to do async call to a web service without blocking current thread and without spawning a new one? Does it fire a request and then the main thread every once in a little checks if there is a Response available in the Future object? I'm aware of how to use it but I want to know what's the deal "under the hood". How would it be implemented in Scala? A simple example if possible would be a nice help.

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the hood play uses [async-http-client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) which is based on NIO. A request will be dispatched and when the server responds, a callback (in this case the completion of the future) will be executed on a thread from the threadpool. This way no thread has to be blocked.

Comment: Well it seems a little bit more clear to me now. Just a thing I don't quite get is how does the thread that invokes callback knows that a response is available if it's not blocked and waiting for a response? Does it check every once in a while if a response has arrived?

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that. NIO provides selectors, that monitor channels for events. A single thread can monitor multiple channels this way and dispatch the callbacks to the threadpool once there is data to be processed.

Comment: @drexin This comment should be part of answer.

Answer (score 1):

Play uses an "execution context", which is typically a thread pool, as described in the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaAsync):

> It’s important to understand which thread code runs on with futures.
>   In the two code blocks above, there is an import on Plays default
>   execution context. This is an implicit parameter that gets passed to
>   all methods on the future API that accept callbacks. The execution
>   context will often be equivalent to a thread pool, though not
>   necessarily.

So no new threads are spawned, but only because there is already a pool of threads available for such work.

Comment: So basically that means that the main thread uses a thread from a thread pool to query a web service? Does that thread from a pool then blocks and waits for a response from a web service? What's the point of async WS client then if you have to occupy a new thread that waits for a response?

Comment: I think drexin has covered this - the callback is triggered by lower-level async IO system calls (e.g. Linux `select`/`poll`/`epoll`), which are abstracted over by Java NIO libraries, so this doesn't tie up lots of Threads.